# Can't open babel/issues link

Tags: github, babeljs

Something's wrong with babel issues on github.

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues redirects to https://github.com/babel/babel/pulls, direct links to issue (e.g. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2679) show 404 page not found.

Is this only me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh, look like they've moved the issues tracker to https://phabricator.babeljs.io/

direct links to issues became https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T${ID}, e.g. https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2679